# Position Sticky, изменить поведение

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать что-то вроде гибрида между **position: fixed** и **position: sticky**?

в данном примере я хочу чтобы **header__bottom** вёл себя как **position: sticky**
но, так как он находится в блоке **header**, **sticky** работает только в его пределах.

Как сделать чтобы **sticky** для **header__bottom** работал на всю длину документа, не вынося **header__bottom** за пределы **header**

p.s Плагины JQUERY и похожие решения не интересуют) Желательно вообще обойтись без JS

```css
.header {
  height: 300px;
  background: silver;
}

.header__top, .header__bottom {
  height: 50px;
}

.header__bottom {
  background: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.body {
  height: 700px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header__top"></div>
    <div class="header__bottom"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    body
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "...не вынося header__bottom за пределы header" - тогда никак.

Comment: только с помощью js, выставляя стили в нужный момент